# data from a pinia store does not update nuxt js

Tags: nuxt.js, pinia

**This is my store code, where I use both methods and computed properties**

```js
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { useSelectedFilterStore } from '~/store/SelectedFilterStore';
import { getCurrentMonth as month, getCurrentDay as day } from '~/plugins/current-date';

export const useCardStore = defineStore("CardStore", {
  state: () => ({ // alias data
    cards: [],
    eventCards: [],
    eventTrending: [],
    artistPopular: [],
    eventSuggest: false,
    extendCard: false,
    search: '',
    eventCarousel: '',
    searchOrder: '',
    selectedLocation: '',
    selectedCalendar: '',
    selectedTicket: '',
    generic: true,
    month: month(),
    day: day(),
  }),
  getters: { // alias computed
    setValue: (state) => {
      const SelectedFilterStore = useSelectedFilterStore();
      state.searchOrder = SelectedFilterStore.searchOrder;
      state.selectedLocation = SelectedFilterStore.selectedLocation;
      state.selectedCalendar = SelectedFilterStore.selectedCalendar;
      state.selectedTicket = SelectedFilterStore.selectedTicket;
    },

    filtered(state) {
      function compare(a, b) {
        if (a.start < b.start) return -1;
        if (a.start > b.start) return 1;
        return 0;
      }
      if (state.selectedLocation == 'ovunque' && state.selectedCalendar == 'tutte le date' && state.selectedTicket == 'tutte le categorie') {
        state.generic = true;
      }
      return this.filterByLocation(this.filterByCalendar(this.filterByTicket(state.cards))).sort(compare)
    },

    filterEvent(state) {
      return this.filterEventByLocation(this.filterEventByCalendar(state.eventCards))
    },

    extend: (state) => {
      if (state.selectedLocation == 'ovunque' && state.selectedCalendar == 'tutte le date' && state.selectedTicket != '') {
        return state.extendCard = true;
      } else if (state.selectedTicket != '' && state.selectedTicket != 'tutte le categorie') {
        return state.extendCard = false;
      } else if (state.selectedLocation == 'ovunque' && state.selectedCalendar != '' && state.selectedTicket != '') {
        return state.extendCard = true;
      }
      return state.extendCard = false;
    },

    suggest: (state) => {
      if (state.generic) {
        return state.eventSuggest = true;
      }
      if (state.filtered.length < 1) {
        return state.eventSuggest = true;
      }
      return state.eventSuggest = false;
    }
  },

  actions: { // alias methods
    async fill() {
      this.cards = (await import("~/data/cards.json")).default;
      this.eventCards = (await import("~/data/event.json")).default;
      this.eventTrending = (await import("~/data/eventTrending.json")).default;
      this.artistPopular = (await import("~/data/artistMustPopular.json")).default;
      // this.cards = (await axios.get('end point')).data
    },

    filterByLocation: function(cards) {
      if (this.selectedLocation == 'ovunque' || this.selectedLocation == '')  return cards;

      this.generic = false;
      return cards.filter(card =>
        card.city.toLowerCase().includes(this.selectedLocation.toLowerCase()),
      )
    },

    filterEventByLocation: function(eventCards) {
      if (this.selectedLocation == 'ovunque' || this.selectedLocation == '') return eventCards;

      if (this.selectedLocation != '' && this.selectedLocation != 'ovunque' && this.selectedTicket == ''
          || this.selectedTicket == 'tutte le categorie' && this.selectedCalendar == ''
          || this.selectedCalendar == 'tutte le date' ) {
        return eventCards.filter(event =>
          event.event == 'tour' && event.city.toLowerCase().includes(this.selectedLocation.toLowerCase())
        );
      }
      return eventCards;
    },

    filterByCalendar: function(cards) {
      if (this.selectedCalendar == 'questo mese') {
        this.generic = false;
        return cards.filter(card =>
          card.start.toLowerCase().includes(this.month) ||
          card.end.toLowerCase().includes(this.month)
        )
      } else if (this.selectedCalendar == 'oggi') {
        this.generic = false;
        return cards.filter(card =>
          card.start.toLowerCase().split(' ')[0].includes(this.day) && card.start.toLowerCase().includes(this.month) ||
          card.end.toLowerCase().split(' ')[0].includes(this.day) && card.end.toLowerCase().includes(this.month)
        )
      } else if (this.selectedCalendar == 'tutte le date' || this.selectedCalendar == '') {
        return cards
      }
      this.generic = false;
      return cards.filter(card =>
        card.start.toLowerCase().includes(this.selectedCalendar.toLowerCase().substring(0,3)) ||
        card.end.toLowerCase().includes(this.selectedCalendar.toLowerCase().substring(0,3))
      )
    },

    filterEventByCalendar: function(eventCards) {
      if (this.selectedCalendar != '' && this.selectedCalendar != 'tutte le date') {
        return eventCards.filter(event =>
          event.event != 'tour'
        )
      }
      return eventCards
    },

    filterByTicket: function(cards) {
      if (this.selectedTicket == 'tutte le categorie' || this.selectedTicket == '') {
        return cards
      }
      this.generic = false;
      return cards.filter(card =>
        card.event.toLowerCase().includes(this.selectedTicket.toLowerCase())
      )
    },
  }
})
```

**Here I import my store into my component with the use of setup**

```js
<script>
import { useCardStore } from '~/store/CardStore'

export default {
  setup() {
    const CardStore = useCardStore();
    CardStore.fill();
    return { CardStore }
  },

}
</script>
```

my problem:
When I go to filter the data, they only update if I have the devTools open.
What did I do wrong? I can't find a solution, and as if the data is not being recalled.

Comment: `fill` is async method, you should `await ` for this during using it in setup.  Not better to use `script setup`? Look here: https://insidewebdev.com/blog/how-to-setup-pinia-in-nuxt3

Answer (score 0):

**I forgot to post the part of the template where I use and recall the store**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <HeaderComponent />

    <ExplorerComponent
      :title="'esplora eventi:'"
      :description="'Trova quello che ti piace, dove e quando vuoi tu'"
      :search="CardStore.titleSearch"
      :img="'bg-explorer1.png'"
    />

    <ResultsComponent
      :cards="CardStore.filtered"
      :search_order="CardStore.searchOrder"
      :generic="CardStore.generic"
    />

    <EventsComponents
      v-animate-on-scroll
      v-if="!CardStore.suggest && CardStore.filterEvent.length > 0"
      :title="CardStore.eventCarousel"
      :cards="CardStore.filterEvent"
      :share="true"
      :extend="CardStore.extend"
      :event_visible="false"
    />

    <EventsComponents
      v-animate-on-scroll
      v-if="CardStore.eventSuggest"
      :title="'artisti più popolari '"
      :cards="CardStore.artistPopular"
      :share="false"
      :extend="false"
      :event_visible="false"
    />

    <EventsComponents
      v-animate-on-scroll
      v-if="CardStore.eventSuggest"
      :title="'eventi di tendenza '"
      :cards="CardStore.eventTrending"
      :share="true"
      :extend="true"
      :event_visible="false"
    />

    <CarouselLocationComponent />
    <ServiceComponent />
    <footer-component :border="true" />
  </div>
</template>
```